# Пользователь отменил действие

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Еще рас всем доброго времени суток
Возникла такая проблема (WPF).
Есть обработчик нажатия, он выполняется, то есть запускает файл на установку,
Но если пользователь отменит установку то программа зависает, и выдает исключение что пользователь отменил действие.
В чем может быть дело подскажите пожалуйста.

```
private void InstallLBSelectCh(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        switch (InstallLB.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                p.Start();

                break;
            case 1:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                p.Start();
                break;
            case 2:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                p.Start();
                break;
            default: goto case 0;
        }

    }
```

Пока что нашел только такое решение

```
private void InstallLBSelectCh(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        switch (InstallLB.SelectedIndex)
        {
            default: case 0:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                try
                {
                    p.Start();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Canceled by User");
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                p.Start();
                break;
            case 2:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[InstallLB.SelectedIndex];
                p.Start();
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Если у вас отмена через CancellationToken, то в этом нет нечего плохого, просто обработайте ошибку через try/catch. А вот goto - это плохо... Лучше объедините case (`default: case0:`), чем перекидывайте через goto!

Comment: В том то и дело что отмены у меня нету, по этому выскакивает исключение, и я не могу додумать как реализовать то что пользователь отменил установку файла,и что бы программа при этом не зависла а продолжила работу, но вывела сообщение пользователю о том что он отменил данное действие.